# Why did Voldemort's father leave his mother?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

I recall that one of the major resentments that led Tom Riddle to hate his father was the fact that he left the family. I don't recall any details of how and why he did. Was it ever specified?

Comment: Wasn't it because their son was such an obnoxious brat he couldn't stand him anymore?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's specified in Half-Blood Prince (HP6), however only as Dumbledore's guess (but, as we learn in the end of Deathly Hallows, his "guesses have usually been good", to quote himself :)

I'll quote a small portion - hopefully it's within fair use.

The context of the following conversation was Dumbledore explaining to Harry the story of the Gaunts and origins of Voldemort, and speculating that Merope (Riddle's mother) used a love potion to besot the nobleman Tom Riddle senior with her.

> 'What went wrong?' asked Harry. 'Why did the love potion stop working?'
>
> 'Again, this is guesswork,' said Dumbledore, 'but I believe that Merope, who was deeply in love with her husband, could not bear to continue enslaving him by magical means. I believe that she made the choice to stop giving him the potion. Perhaps, besotted as she was, she had convinced herself that he would by now have fallen in love with her in return. Perhaps she thought he would stay for the baby's sake. If so, she was wrong on both counts. He left her, never saw her again, and never troubled to discover what became of his son.'

Answer (score 20):

Merope Gaunt used a Love Potion to seduce Tom Riddle Sr. Eventually she let the Love Potion wear off, hoping that he would love her for real.

> "Within a few months of their runaway marriage, Tom Riddle reappeared at the manor house in Little Hangleton without his wife. The rumour flew around the neighbour­hood that he was talking of being 'hoodwinked' and 'taken in'... He left her, never saw her again, and never troubled to discover what became of his son."

Obviously he was probably more than a little angry at having been tricked into a marriage and child he didn't want.

Harry Potter Wiki: [ref](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Tom_Riddle_Sr.)

Comment: It's not a sure thing that it was a love potion that was used.  But it certainly seems to be the most likely case.

Answer (score 1):

In the sixth book it becomes clear that Tom Riddle left Voldemort's mother when he discovered what she was. 
In the fourth book, when the old man, Frank, worked at the Riddle home I assume that was Voldemort's dad, and his parents.

Answer (score -1):

She was a rapist who forced him to marry her, then made him have a child he didn't want by using magic.

Comment: Hi, welcome to scifi.stackexchange.com. Can you cite specific evidence to support this answer? Was this established in any particular movie or book?

Comment: This seems wildly speculative.  Do you have any evidence for this at all?